# Django-cms - Selected templates never displayed

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I recently started to work with Django-cms. I just created two templates **base.html** and **home.html** (this latter extends base.html), registered them into *settings.py* like this :

```
CMS_TEMPLATES = (
    ('base.html', 'Default'),
    ('home.html', 'Homepage'),
)
```

I've created my home page within the admin and selected the *Homepage* template but the content of this file is never shown.

I have followed the instructions from the documentation, but I don't understand where my mistake.

Anyone has any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Did you check your urls.py? 
You have to make sure that you make a regualr expression that maps your views to your url and in your views you then call/load the template.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/

Answer (score 1):

Little example on Kyle Calica's post:

in your urls.py you add something like this: (in your myproject/ folder where also your settings.py file is)

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include('myapp.urls')),
)
```

then in myapp.urls you need something like:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.myview, name='myview'),
)
```

and then in your view:

```
def test(request):
    return render(request, "my template.html")
```

and last in your template extend your base:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

edit:
These are simple basics of django. if you dont grasp them i suggest you run the tutorial again and try to understand what they are actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Hans (and @Kyle Calica-St), Thanks for your answer, but I have a correct urls configuration. I just created a new Blog app and I encountered the same problem. Here is my files :

**settings.py**

```
CMS_TEMPLATES = (
    ('base.html', 'Default'),
    ('home.html', 'Homepage'),
    ('news/home_news.html', 'News'),
)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
    # Homepage
    url(r'^$', home_view),

    # News
    url(r'^news/', include('apps.news.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)
```

**views.py**

```
def home_view(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

**home.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load cms_tags %}

{% block base_content %}
    {% placeholder home_content %}
    <p>Hello World !</p>
{% endblock %}
```

*Idem for news app*

When I access to the homepage, I don't see the "*Hello World !*" **p** HTML tag.
I tried to change the order of the urls matches with no results.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? Im assuming you did.